# Upgrade Cassandra 3.0 to 4.0

Tags: cassandra

I need to upgrade 3.0.27 version of Cassandra to at least 4.0.11. Can I upgrade directly from 3.0.27, or should I upgrade first to 3.11 and then to 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to upgrade to Cassandra 4.0 directly from the 3.0 line.  There is no need to perform an intermediate upgrade to 3.11.

Here's a link to some general steps for upgrading from 3.x to 4.x: https://www.datastax.com/learn/whats-new-for-cassandra-4/migrating-cassandra-4x

Answer (score 1):

You could also use tools like [**Cassandra Data Migration (CDM)** in combination with **Zero Downtime Migration (ZDM)** proxies](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/migrate/introduction.html) to directly migrate off of your existing `3.0.27` to a more recent `4.1.latest` version directly by spinning a new cluster with newer version of Apache Cassandra. Just so you know `5.x` GA is just around the corner too in a couple months/weeks.

If you want to do it by hand yourself for an in-place upgrade, you could follow [this fantastic documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/luna-cassandra/docs/guides/upgrade/overview.html) that details the steps in greater details. Although, it's possible to achieve a direct upgrade, please see the best practice recommendation below,

> When upgrading to a new major version, it’s recommended that you first upgrade the cluster to the latest patch release on your current version. Fixes included in the latest patch release can help avoid issues and reduce the overall level of risk associated with the upgrade process. For this reason, it’s a general best practice to have a continual upgrade strategy that keeps the cluster on the latest patch release of the current major version.